# How to render ListView.builder and GridView.builder on one page

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to rend ListView.builder and GridView.builder on one page i tried this code but working
difficulty in rendring these two builders both will display vertical list and scrollable.

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Title")),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
            primary: false,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, position) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(choices[position]),
              );
            },
            itemCount: choices.length,
          ),
          GridView.builder(
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                childAspectRatio: (3 / 2),
              ),
              itemCount: personas.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  child: Card(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(personas[index]?.fullName),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap `Column` with `SingleChildScrollView` which will resolve the rendering issue. Add

`physics: ScrollPhysics()`, which will allow `ListView` and `GridView` to scroll vertically

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Title")),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text('List Item'),
                );
              },
              itemCount: 20,
            ),
            GridView.builder(
                physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  childAspectRatio: (3 / 2),
                ),
                itemCount: 15,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Card(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text('Grid Item'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: You should CustomScrollView and SliverList, SliverGrid for this.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them in containers and give them proper height or width.

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Title")),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
         Container(
          height:200,
           child: ListView.builder(
            primary: false,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, position) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(choices[position]),
              );
            },
            itemCount: choices.length,
          ),
        ),
         Container(
          height:200,
            child: GridView.builder(
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                childAspectRatio: (3 / 2),
              ),
              itemCount: personas.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  child: Card(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(personas[index]?.fullName),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
           )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: how to give dynamic height because my items will keep increasing day by day

Comment: There is no way to set dynamic heights. You can calculate the height by multiplying the initial height to the item count.

Comment: or can you show the screenshot of what exactly you are trying to do? I can show an alternative solution that is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution this can done by using slivers

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(appBarTitle)),
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(title(choices[index])),
                  selected: isSame(choices[index], selected),
                  onTap: () {
                    onSelected(choices[index]);
                  },
                );
              }, childCount: choices.length),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: GridView.builder(
                  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    childAspectRatio: (3 / 2),
                  ),
                  itemCount: personas?.length ?? 0,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      child: Card(
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(personas[index]?.fullName),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ));
```